# error C2664: "void flat::set_rooms(unsigned int)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [2]" в "unsigned int"

Tags: c++, преобразование

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class flat
{
private:
    char *adress;
    unsigned int floor;
    float area;
    unsigned int rooms;
    float price;
public:
    void set_adress(char *cur_adress)
        {
        adress = cur_adress;
        }
           void set_floor(unsigned int cur_floor)
              {
              floor = cur_floor; 
              }
                void set_area(float cur_area)
                    {
                    area = cur_area;
                    }
                    void set_rooms(unsigned int cur_rooms)
                        {
                        rooms = cur_rooms;
                        }
                         void set_price(float cur_price)
                                {
                                price = cur_price;
                                }
char *get_adress()
{
    return adress;
}
unsigned int get_floor()
{
    return floor;
}
float get_area()
{
    return area;
}
unsigned int get_rooms()
{
    return rooms;
}
float get_price()
{
    return price;
}

        flat(char *cur_adress
        , unsigned int cur_floor
        , float cur_area
        , unsigned int cur_rooms
        , float cur_price)
        : floor(cur_floor),
        area(cur_area),
        rooms(cur_rooms),
        price(cur_price)
    {
        adress = cur_adress;
    }

        flat() : adress(" "), floor(0), area(0), rooms(0), price(0)//конструктор
    {}

    flat:: ~ flat()
    {
        delete[]adress;  //Деструктор 
    }
};

void main()
{


    flat flat1;
    cout << "Input: \nAdress:\t\t";
    flat1.set_adress("Metalistov");
    cout << flat1.get_adress();
    cout << "\nFloor:\t\t\t";
    flat1.set_floor("2");
    cout << flat1.get_floor();
    cout << "\nArea: \t\t\t";
    flat1.set_area("25 ");
    cout << flat1.get_area();
    cout << "\nRooms: \t\t";
    flat1.set_rooms("1");
    cout << flat1.get_rooms();
    cout<< "\nPrice of flat: \t";
    flat1.set_price("265");
    cout << flat1.get_price();
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Член класса `rooms` объявлен, как имеющий тип `unsigned int`

```
unsigned int rooms;
```

Соответственно функция `set_rooms`, которая устанавливает значение для данного члена класса,  имеет параметр также типа `unsigned int`

```
void set_rooms(unsigned int cur_rooms)
{
    rooms = cur_rooms;
}
```

Однако вы вызываете эту функцию, передавая в качестве аргумента строковый литерал `"1"`, который имеет тип `const char[2]`, то есть является константным массивом мз двух символов - '1' и '\0':

```
flat1.set_rooms("1");
```

Чтобы по крайней мере это предложение компилировалось, вам в качестве аргумента нужно задать число

```
flat1.set_rooms( 1 );
```